# How to find a string(pattern) in all type of folders(no archives) from the current directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So i want to search for a string(pattern not a fixed string) through all types of folder from my current directory and then append the name of folders that contains the pattern(string) to a file.txt.

my code is :

`for f in *.sh
 do
if [ -f "$f" ];
then
found=$(grep "$1" "$f")
if [ ! -z "$found" ];
then
echo "$f" >> test.txt
fi
fi
done`

What should i do in order to search my pattern through all types of folders not just only .sh and append their names(if it contains the pattern provided as input $1 ). Or maybe is there any change in grep or something?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a shell loop here: grep has a `-r` option for recursive search and a `-l` option to print the names of files with matches.

I would probably add `-I` as well, to exclude binary files from the search. So

```
grep -Irl "$1" . > test.txt
```

(`.` standing for the current directory; change this to whatever directory you wish to start the search from).

Comment: Thanks! It is working but i have one more question.What is the difference between one ">" and two ">>" ?

Comment: @NistorMihnea `>` *overwrites* the target file whereas `>>` *appends* to it. In a loop, you obviously need the latter - with a single grep command you don't (unless you want to preserve the file's previous contents for some other reason).

Comment: Got it.I m grateful to you.